# Which will be the best way to sort vector of unordered map by ascending order of the size of individual map c++

Tags: c++, stl

Suppose, we have a vector of unordered map as **vector<unordered_map<char,int>> recordset;**;

my code looks like this,

```
std::vector<string> inputStrings;
for(int i =0;i<6;i++)
{
    string tmp;
    cin >> tmp;
    inputStrings.push_back(tmp);
}

vector<unordered_map<char,int>> recordset;
for(int i=0;i<(int)inputStrings.size();++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < (int)inputStrings[i].length(); j++)
    {
        (recordset[i])[(inputStrings[i])[j]]++;
    }
}
```

Which will be the efficient way to sort above vector **recordset** in ascending order by size of its map elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) can take 3rd argument to specify how to order elements. Passing lambda function there should be good way. The function shold return `true` if 1st argument should be come before 2nd argument and `false` otherwise.

```
std::sort(recordset.begin(), recordset.end(),
    [](const unordered_map<char,int>& a, const unordered_map<char,int>& b) -> bool {
        return a.size() < b.size();
    }
);
```